# Azure Pipeline - Opening RemoteWebDriver with different credentials

Tags: c#, azure, automation, azure-devops

Basically we set up test automation in one environment(DEV). For this environment we use a users credentials to open the browser for all tests. So in our dev environment we have the same password set up for all users. This will be the same approach in UAT but with a different password

When testing we launch the browser using impersonation and launch the browser as 'run as' for that user

```
private static RemoteWebDriver OpenChromeBrowser(string username) {
var service = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService(driverpath)
```

if user is not null then we do this

```
var pwd = new SecureString()

service.StartDomain = Configurationhelper.Domain
service.StartupUserName = username
service.StartupPassword= = pwd
service.StartupLoadUserProfile = true
```

we store domain and password and other environmental variables in a separate config file as constants.

Our Azure pipeline has 2 separate clients now UAT and DEV pointing to the same artifact. The tasks and Variable are the same for both environments but with different values for urls and db connections

**Main issue:** This wont work now as when we run the tests in UAT they fail straight away with' Password is incorrect' as we have hardcoded the password into our code. So i am looking for the best solution to this

Is there a way to modify this code and to maybe store passwords as secrets in AZURE pipeline variables? so for example in our pipeline variables we would have password for both Dev and UAT. Then launch chromedriver with user credentials set as variables from azure pipeline?

What is the recommended approach in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to modify this code and to maybe store passwords as secrets in AZURE pipeline variables?

The answer is yes.

We are doing the same thing "*store domain and password and other environmental variables in a separate config file as constants*", Let's call it `app.config`, I am not sure if my solution fully meets your requirements, but you can try it.

I defined following in the `app.config`:

```
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="DatabaseName" connectionString="DatabaseURL" />
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

To modify the `DatabaseName` and `DatabaseURL` based on the different environments by the variables in the pipeline Variables, I use the task [Replace Tokens](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens) to modify the `DatabaseName` and `DatabaseURL`.

I change the `app.config` in the repo to:

```
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="#{DatabaseName}#" connectionString="#{DatabaseURL}#" />
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

The format of variable in `.config` file is #{DatabaseName}# & #{DatabaseURL}#.

[image]

**Then** define the variables `DatabaseName` and  `DatabaseURL` on the Variables based on the stage as secrets:

[image]

In this case, the `connectionStrings` will be modified to different value based on the stage.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and thank you for the reassurance. I actually found a similar solution also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59962204/how-to-use-environment-variables-set-in-azure-pipeline-in-the-web-config-file-of. So i will use your approach :)